# Handling reconnections in the socket.io server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When the socket.io client performs an (automatic) reconnection - as might happen if a mobile client went to sleep then woke up again - does the server get a reconnect event? Or does it just see a disconnection and fresh connection?

In either case is there a way to

1. identify that it's the same client e.g. by a unique client id that persists across connections
2. have the client automatically re-join any rooms it was in before

Or do I need to code that functionality manually e.g. by having the client supply the id or rooms itself on reconnection?

I had a read of the socket.io [docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#) and can't see any list of events that the server might receive.

Comment: > I need to code that functionality manually e.g. by having the client supply the id

Comment: Oh ok. Does the server get a `reconnect` event or just a `disconnect`/`connect`?

Comment: there is a reconnect event, check https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/a48365860748a5006f6dd80a710008e18aeac89b/examples/chat/public/main.js#L271

Comment: The link is in client side code - does the server get it too?